# Black eSUN PLA+ has moisture damage straight out of the box. Is this normal?

Tags: filament, stringing

I just recieved a roll of eSUN black PLA+ and I have found out it has moisture damage after using it for 2 days. I was previously using a roll of eSUN orange PLA+ and it worked really well. So I ran a stringing test just to make sure the settings were right for the black roll and the result was terrible. So I spent a full day messing with slicer settings as moisture damage was last on my list for the issue since the roll was brand new. But with no improvement I decided to dry out a sample of filament just to try and this was the result.

[image]

Left is filament straight from the roll, middle is dried out filament and orange as a control. So now I  know the problem is this normal for eSUN filaments? Should I dry out filaments as soon as I take them out of the box? I didn't have this issue with my orange roll.

Comment: In my experience some variability between spools of filament is to be expected, even when they are the same brand. Settings and parameters that are optimal for one spool may not work as well for another. Moisture absorption is one of several possible contributors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is plausible. Please weight your bobin and dry it then weight it again to know how much water you extracted.